# It names a place where many people live

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> What's this word? It names a place where many people live.
>   Change a letter, it's a person no one will forgive.
>   Lose a letter, it's a popular vacation place;
>   Change a letter and it means "too loud" or "in your face."
>   Change a letter, it's an action that I guarantee
>   You have never taken. Tell me what this word may be!

Comment: Is the letter order always preserved, as individual letters are changed or removed?

Comment: @wildBillMunson Yes. No anagramming is involved.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The answer is

> PARISH.

Explanation:

> A PARISH is a place where many people live.
> A PARIAH is someone nobody will forgive.
> PARIS is a popular vacation place.
> GARISH is too loud or in your face
> And if you had PERISHed, you wouldn't be reading the riddle in the first place!

Answer (score 8):

The answer is

> PARISH

Change a letter:

> PARIAH

Lose a letter:

> PARIS

Change a different letter:

> GARISH

But an action that I guarantee? Haven't solved that bit yet.

Comment: I'm guessing you couldn't come up with the final letter change to make it work?

Comment: And the final line?

Comment: I couldn't get that bit. Didn't know that the word Deusovi gives, which is surely correct, could be used as a noun, but apparently it is in informal Australian English.